# Logins through phone app don't count towards enthusiast/fanatic

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, consecutive-days

I assumed that logging in through the stack exchange phone app would count towards the Fanatic/Enthusiast badges. Now I actually see my consecutive login days on stackoverflow down to 1 from 91 since I used only the phone app (Android version) for a day. Is this supposed to happen?

**Update:** The question that I had was answered. However I have just one follow-up question, whether there is any way for me to recover the lost days or is that not possible at all. It makes complete sense that there is no way to distinguish the requests made through API, but still, I cannot anticipate that I would have to ask such a question before I actually find out that my consecutive activity has been lost (meaning consecutive days on the site).

Comment: Is this a third-party application or is it the mobile *site*? The latter should *most definitely* count towards the enthusiast badge.

Comment: @casperOne It is the stack remote app downloaded from the android market (google play). I guess it's third party.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It *used* to be that access through a mobile app would not count towards the badges, see the old answer below.

As of August 2013, mobile app use counts towards the badges, see [Last seen not updating when using Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app/193269#193269).

---

*Original answer, December 2012*:

Accessing your Stack Exchange data through the API does not count towards your fanatic and enthusiast badge progress.

External applications such as the iPhone app use the API, not direct access to the site. If you use the mobile web interface instead, you are seen to use the site actively and such access is counted towards the badges.

It would be almost impossible to distinguish *automated* use of the API data from interactive use, so I don't think this will ever change.

As for your update: no, there is no way to recover the days lost.

Comment: It would be nice if this was stated in the faq or in the badges section. It really pisses me off that I have lost half a month because half the time I am answering questions using the ipad app. If I had seen this prior I would never have installed the app at all.

Comment: I figured I would ping the newer answer; I saw the linked answer. Is there a list on what qualifies as an interaction via the iOS app that will count towards the Fanatic badge?

Comment: @Arc676: I don't think so, just like there is no such list for what qualifies as an interaction with the website.