# Last seen not updating when using Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, android-app, last-activity

This isn't directly related to the app, but probably more on the APIs it's using. The last seen on the profile page doesn't seem to reflect that I'm actively using the Android app, or taking actions. I was able to vote on items and the last seen property on the profile page said I was last seen 50 minutes ago, when I was using a computer.

I'm assuming it won't count as a visit for the Enthusiast and Fantic badges either. I don't want someone angrily posting on Meta swearing they used the app for a day, yet they lost the consecutive days and has to prove it by showing they voted for something (we're probably far from this situation since it's alpha...)

Comment: I was just going to ask if this is intended behavior, or if it is simply disabled on the alpha version, or if it is a "bug"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We're now counting access to a site via the app for both "last seen" and the "daily site access" for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.

As is true with the sites, we don't actually count all access; only those actions we consider "real".  For the mobile app, this basically means accessing the feed doesn't count; we'll probably tweak what we consider "real" over time.

Comment: Is there a list describing what "real" means? I don't intend this question to be specifically for the mobile apps, but for the site in general. Through a browser or through the mobile app.

Comment: Some days I just visit SO to make sure I don't break my streak. Good to know that this wouldn't count. I second @axiopisty question regarding if there is a formal description what actions count towards the streak.

Comment: Just an observation: I think using the app doesn't count as a visit to all your accounts. I can't lay my finger on the exact logic behind it but what I've seen is that when I visit an account using the app just one or two of my accounts gain a visit count.

Comment: So, any list of "real" actions?