# Interaction with the site on the app should count towards Enthusiast/Fanatic

Tags: discussion, bug, status-norepro, android-app, consecutive-days

If I do any of the below, which would *normally* constitute "activity" on any Stack Exchange site (including mobile):

- View my profile
- Vote on any question or comment
- Visit one or more questions

...then Stack Exchange considers me to have "visited" the site.

If I do any of the below on the mobile app:

- Vote on any question or comment
- Visit one or more questions

...then Stack Exchange does *not* consider me to have visited the site.

If one wants the app to have feature parity with the mobile site, then shouldn't my participation within the app also count towards the Enthusiast/Fanatic badge?

Comment: Technically it just accesses the SE API, which means you'd have to update the API and allow it to accept calls to update that access information.

Comment: But I guess the mobile website doesn't have this problem?

Comment: @Szymon The mobile website is not an app. It's all the exact same features of Stack Exchange, just with a different theme designed for mobile devices. That's it.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app

Comment: This seems like it's a bug rather than a feature-request since we did this logic for [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already the case.

Looking at your history, I see a number of days where you got the daily site access via using the mobile app.  For example, you got credit for meta today when you first visited [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200197/prevent-suggested-edits-on-pre-pre-code-blocks).

Is there a particular missed record somewhere you've noticed?

Comment: No, I'm thinking that I sat on this bug for too long.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Indeed this is wrong from my point of view. I visit the site at weekends only via App - so I normally get 5 days enthusiast - and on saturday and sunday there is a zero again... :( I too think this is wrong behaviour...