# Does using iOS App 'count' as logging into site?

Tags: support, login, ios-app

If so, which site that I use updates the "seen X mins ago"? All? Only the one I actually used to log in originally?

I was planning on testing this myself, but realized there is no way to check that value without updating it.

Comment: I know I lost my fanatic streak using the app, but I may have been limited to the Feed on that day

Comment: Side note: You can always use an alternate browser/incognito session to test.

Comment: @Andrew'saUnitato ah, I didn't realize that was on the public profile

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does, as per [this answer on a question for the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app/193269#193269).

> We're now counting access to a site via the app for both "last seen" and the "daily site access" for the Enthusiast and Fanatic badges.
>
> As is true with the sites, we don't actually count all access; only those actions we consider "real". For the mobile app, this basically means accessing the feed doesn't count; we'll probably tweak what we consider "real" over time.

Comment: Does that also apply to the iOS app?

Comment: @Andrew Well both of them use the same API to fetch data. Doesn't make sense why one would and the other wouldn't.

Comment: Oh, duh! Of course they would... silly me... Thanks!