# Do iOS app visits count to your consecutive visits

Tags: support, ios-app, consecutive-days

The title says it all, just wondered if accessing the iOS will count towards your consecutive visited days.

Comment: [Looks like it does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193269/152859).