# iOS App : Does visiting the app count to consecutive days?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, ios-app, consecutive-days, last-activity

> - Does the `consecutive days` on the **profile page** reflect that I'm actively using the iOS app ?
> - Is this count added to the `consecutive days` ?
> - OR does only visiting the website count ?

*P.S. I know that an answer for the android app is already [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191781/last-seen-not-updating-when-using-android-app) ; but I sure will be grateful if someone can tell me whether the same happens for the iOS App*